# Renaming multiple files

Tags: find, rename

My security cameras recorder (located in distant place), FTP`s to my server video files after any event. It automatically creates sudirs with name containing date of day. Using find and ffmpeg commands, server converts DAV file to AVI and remove DAV file. After that, each video file has name like this:

```
19.38.41-19.38.55[M][@0][0].dav.avi
```

I want to change above name to format like this:

```
19-38-41.avi
```

How can I do it in the same "find" command line

I try to use as the first, syntax like this:

```
find $katalog -name '*.dav.avi' -execdir rename 's/\.dav//' {} \;
```

But the result was:

```
rename:not enough arguments
```

Any idea whats wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On linux distribution are present two `rename` utility.

```
   rename [ -v ] [ -n ] [ -f ] perlexpr [ files ]
```

and

```
   rename [options] expression replacement file...
```

On Ubuntu [**rename**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/prename.1.html) command follow first synopsis, while in other linux distribution, [**rename**](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rename.1.html) command synopsis is the second one.

On ubuntu such `rename` is [**rename.ul**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/rename.ul.1.html) and if third parameter is missing it will return:

```
   rename:not enough arguments
```

I guess you are not using Ubuntu, in any case, try this:

```
   find $katalog -name '*.dav.avi' -execdir rename .dav.avi .avi {} \;
```

Tested on lubuntu 12.04 with `rename.ul`

---

Instead of `rename`, you can use this script:

```
   find . -name "*.dav.avi" | while read file; do newFile=`echo $file | awk '{ print substr($0,1,match($0,"\\[")-1) ".avi"; }'`; mv $file $newFile; done
```